# Python, Sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

name|num|num|num|num
    name|num|num|num|num
    name|num|num|num|num

How i can sort this list on need me field (2,3,4,5) ?
Sorry for my enlish.

**Update**

Input:

```
str|10|20
str|1|30
```

Sort by first field (1,10):

```
str|1|30
str|10|20
```

Sort by second field(20,30):

```
str|10|20
str|1|30
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Maybe provide an example of expected output and some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start with a list of strings, start by splitting each row into a list:

```
data = [line.split('|') for line in input]
```

Then sort by whatever index you want:

```
sort_index = 1
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda line: int(line[sort_index]))
```

The [Python sorting guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) has a lot more information.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the operator module function "itemgetter" instead of the lambda functions. That is faster and allows multiple levels of sorting.

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = (line.split('|') for line in input.split('\n')) 
sort_index = 1
sorted(data, key=itemgetter(sort_index))
```

Comment: +1 Optimal solution imo. I'd just store the result of `sorted(...)` in a variable, as it doesn't sort in place (and in-place sorting with `data.sort()` isn't available for generators). But you probably meant that.

Comment: +1, and agree that the last line would be better as: data.sort(key=..).  Also, the poster's original request was for sort_index = (1,2,3,4), which is how one specifies compound keys using Python's 0-based indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort on a specific *key*, which tells the sort function how to evaluate the entries to be sorted -- that is, how we decide which of two entries is bigger.  In this case, we'll first split up each string by the pipe, using `split` (for example, `"a|b|c".split("|")` returns `["a", "b", "c"]`) and then grab whichever entry you want.

To sort on the first "num" field:

```
sorted(lines, key=(lambda line : line.split("|")[1])
```

where `lines` is a list of the lines as you mention in the question.  To sort on a different field, just change the number in brackets.